# Cannot compile Centura SQLWindows/32 apps on Windows 10

Tags: guptateamdeveloper, centura

I have a couple of Centura SQLWindows/32 legacy apps, which still require the occasional update even though they were superceded by web services long ago. So far, SQLWindows/32 and the compiled apps themselves run fine on any OS platform I've run them on, up to and including the latest Windows 10 Pro and even Server 2016.

What it won't do is **compile** on these OS versions. So, I keep a Windows XP machine handy, copy my app files across and compile them into executables. Works fine, all good.

Naturally, I'd like to get rid of the XP box and compile on Windows 10, but this is what I get;

[image: Centura SQLWindows/32 v1.5 Ptf 3]

**My Question:**

Has anyone successfully figured out how to compile SQLWindows/32 apps on Windows 10..?

(I should qualify that by saying I'm not about to waste money upgrading SQLWindows..!)

Further qualification: Although I got the 1.5.1 update as part of my support package way back when, I never used it because they changed the way the run time libraries worked, meaning major surgery had to done to install routines, while  the chap who created some specialised Dlls that I integrate with died along with the source code. RIP. I threw my hands up in horror at the prospect of having to rebuild it all, especially as the compiled exes kept working fine!

**CORRECTION: It's the Build to exe that doesn't work, compiles fine!!!**

From there on, I just copied the Centura installation 1.5-Ptf3 (which was supposedly near equivalent to the 1.5.1 release) directory to a new machine as an old one died, i.e. I didn't install from media and that may well be the root of the problem. Nevertheless, the editor and test run worked fine with this less than optimum process, except I couldn't compile on any OS later than XP.

Looks like I may have no choice but to dig out my 1.5.1 media, install it on Windows 10 and and see if the compile works...

Answer (score 1):

Kia ora  Rangi !
All versions of SQLWindows ( 32 and 64 bit ) will compile on Windows 10 . Nothing special needed.  I run and compile v1.5.1 thru to v7.1 on Windows 10 no problems. There is something else at fault on your Win10 machine  stopping the compile .
It looks like maybe your development environment ( as opposed to your run-time files ) may not be properly installed on your Win 10 .   Are you able to re-install the Development environment on your Win 10 machine ?  Is your exe flagged as 'Read Only' ( this will also stop a compile ) .
ps What ver of SQLWindows are you running - I may be able to send you the dev environment files you need. 
Steve
Tauranga N.Z.

**Addendum**:
To qualify my earlier Note above , there is a very definite and recommended Compatibility Matrix that details the *certified* combinations of SQLWindows / OS / dB , as opposed to those that work coincidentally together .  Please see the official [**Compatibility Matrix**](http://www.banksidesystems.com/gupta-teamdeveloper--compatibiliy-matrix)   here.

Comment: Hey @GuptaSteve Wow, cool someone with experience of this stuff and sounds promising! Please see my additional edits in my question. (I'm ex-Centron)

Comment: Greetings Rangi  Good to see someone else Gupta-like in NZ.   You may like to join our global Gupta SQLWindows / TeamDeveloper Community Forum, and post your question there.  Its a very active community - and someone may have experienced the same as you, and have alternate suggestions. If you physically login - you get even more information. The ( new ) Forum is here: http://forum.tdcommunity.net/  and an ( older read-only ) forum is here: http://support.guptatechnologies.com/supportforum/   Greetings from Tauranga .

Comment: p.s.  I see that you are reluctant to upgrade , but from past experience , the ROI far outweighs the sweat and tears you'll go through trying to maintain v1.5.1 !                                         SQLWindows in now 64bit , UNICODE and .Net enabled.  See the official Compatibilty Matrix here: https://www.banksidesystems.com/gupta-teamdeveloper--compatibiliy-matrix

Comment: Thanks @GuptaSteve really appreciate your enthusiasm for SQLWindows. Only requirement is minor corrections to a complex serial-tcp/ip comms running on physical or VM server. Uses 32-bit libraries coded to specs unchanged 50 years, works perfectly. SQL is rudimentary, 95% of app functionality now migrated/virtualised on Azure in .NET and Android. Further SQLWindows development is limited. Easy if 1.5-Ptf3 build could work on Win10, but of that can't happen then I might as well just stick with the XP build machine. Again, thanks a bunch for your responses and suggestions. Love the Mt :o)